# How to specify the output directory of a given DLL?

Tags: windows, dll, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm using the following `src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
project(foo)
add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp)
set_target_properties(foo
    PROPERTIES
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/$<CONFIG>/subdir
)
```

And on Windows, I'm building the library using:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../src
cmake --build .
```

**Output File:** `~/build/Debug/foo.dll`

**Expected Output File:** `~/build/Debug/subdir/foo.dll`

What am I doing wrong?

It works fine on platforms other than Windows, and it seems like it should work according to the following documentation:

- [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/add_library.html)
- [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/set_target_properties.html)
- [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)
- [cmake-generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Short answer

On Windows, unlike other platforms, you should use `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` instead of `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to specify the output directory of a shared library.

## Long answer

This is documented on the CMake documentation about [Output Artifacts](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#output-artifacts):

> **Runtime Output Artifacts**
>
> A runtime output artifact of a buildsystem
>   target may be:
>
> - The executable file (e.g. .exe) of an executable target created by the
>     add_executable() command.
> - **On DLL platforms: the executable file (e.g.
>     .dll) of a shared library target** created by the add_library() command
>     with the SHARED option. The RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY and
>     RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME target properties may be used to control runtime
>     output artifact locations and names in the build tree.
>
> **Library Output Artifacts**
>
> A library output artifact of a buildsystem
>   target may be:
>
> - The loadable module file (e.g. .dll or .so) of a module library target
>     created by the add_library() command with the MODULE option.
> - **On
>     non-DLL platforms: the shared library file (e.g. .so or .dylib) of a
>     shared library target** created by the add_library() command with
>     the SHARED option. The LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY and
>     LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME target properties may be used to control library
>     output artifact locations and names in the build tree.

But why would CMake make such a difference between DLL platforms (Windows) and non-DLL platforms (macOS, Linux, etc.)?

I couldn't find a source documenting this design decision, but I believe the rationale is that Windows does not support the concept of `rpath`, that is, `.exe` files can't store internally the location of their dependent `.dll` files. Therefore, on Windows, `.dll` files are often stored in the same folder as `.exe` files to make sure that the DLLs are found at runtime. Instead, on Unix systems, shared library files are often stored in a separate `lib` folder, while application binaries are stored in a `bin` folder, which is not a problem because binaries can store the location of their dependencies using `rpath`.

In conclusion, it makes sense for cross-platform development to define both `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
project(foo)
add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp)
set_target_properties(foo
    PROPERTIES
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/$<CONFIG>/lib
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/$<CONFIG>/bin
)
```

Comment: In complex CMake projects with shared libraries, tests and executables I mostly use the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`,  `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variables of the project. They also allow you to set the output directory dependent on the build type, e.g. `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` , `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO`, ...

Comment: @vre If one prefers to use the global variables instead of the per-target properties, sure, you can do that. But the main point remains: on Windows shared libraries will go to `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, while on Linux and macOS, they'll go to `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` :)